# How do you quickly identify object structure in node?

Tags: node.js, object

Is there a way to quickly identify object structure in Node?  I have the following code below, which uses the spotify npm package

```
// *****************  Code for SPOTIFY  *************************

// Return Artist, Song Name, a preview link of the song from Spotify, and the albumn the song is from

//  Search for text variable on spotify.  Console log data

if (nodeArgs=="spotify-this-song") {

spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: text }, function(err, data) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.log('Error occurred: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)); 
});

};
```

This returns the data, but it's difficult for me (a new coder) to determine the object levels and to output the information I'm looking for (Artist, Song Name, a preview link of the song from Spotify, the albumn, etc)

Is there an easier way to graphically see the object structure?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for.  You could just do `console.log(data)` and a good debugger (like in Chrome) will let you see the whole object and expand/collapse levels.

Comment: Debugging in Chrome might be helpful https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: agree with jfriend and Andy... seems what you are asking for is a debugger... you can run your server app in [node_webkit](https://nwjs.io/) and access its debugger same as doing it for web page

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no easier way than `JSON.stringify` which you are already using, you might want to change `2` to `4` for a bit more spaces and possibly better readablity. If you want to seee something in the browser you may want to copy your json string and use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to beautify it.

Answer (score 2):

Try node's `util` library, available by default (You require it like a normal module), with the `inspect` function (which can have a configurable depth and some more options, like use colors). This link might help you: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

> The util.inspect() method returns a string representation of object that is primarily useful for debugging. Additional options may be passed that alter certain aspects of the formatted string.

Here's an example of usage:

```
var util = require("util"); // Require the util library, you have it by default.
var options = { depth: 3 }; // Set options to inspect with depth of 3.
// then with the object...
console.log(util.inspect(obj, options)); // options are optional.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different console commands that format the data differently.  A couple that might be useful for an object are:

```
console.dir(data);

console.table(data);
```

If you're using node version 6.3 or greater you can use the --inspect parameter to debug the app in your browser: $ node --inspect index.js and then set a break-point to take a closer look at the variable.